# Show that the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ are the same for a linear operator $T$ on finite dimensional space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

the following question has me stumped: Show that for a linear operator $T$ defined on a finite-dimensional space, the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ are the same. Its given in a tutorial chapter on finite-frame theory without proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*T$, and $v$ is a corresponding eigenvector, what happens if you apply $TT^*$ to $Tv$? (Caution: some care is needed if $\lambda = 0$ and $Tv = 0$.)

Comment: thank you... should have seen this before.